# How to send a message to a group without a bot in TELEGRAM using JAVA/Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, telegram, telegram-webhook

I have been asked to research in How to send a message to a telegram channel without a bot using JAVA. I am totally new to this Telegram API and all the examples I found uses a BOT. Could anyone please help me to start with a sample code with NO Bots please.

Thanks and really appreciate your views on this.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't work much by Java

But in general, you can use the following ways to send a message to the telegram:

- Send by [Bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods) (You can run it on your system or server)
- Send by [Telegram Cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) (You can run it on your system or server)
- send by [Telegram desktop client](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop).(You can run it on your system or server)
- Send by clients that can interact with Core API Telegram, for example, [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) for Python language, [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto) for PHP language, [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) for C# language, [Kotlogram](https://kotlogram.readme.io/v0.0.6) for Java language and Etc...
  (You can run it on your system or server)

Comment: thanks buddy. but I am looking for a way to send messages to a telegram news channel without using the BotApi. Is it possible with those tools you suggested?

Comment: If you do not want to do this through your bot, you should do this with a telegram account like a normal user through this tool. for example, read this page https://kotlogram.readme.io/docs/send-a-message

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to [`tdlib/td`](https://github.com/tdlib/td), a cross-platform library for building Telegram clients created by Telegram in C++. You can use it in Java via JNI (Java Native Interface). They provide a [Java client example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java) to help you get started and build your own client.

Their example provides the code for sending a message:

```
private static void sendMessage(long chatId, String message) {
    // initialize reply markup just for testing
    TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton[] row = {new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton("https://telegram.org?1", new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButtonTypeUrl()), new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton("https://telegram.org?2", new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButtonTypeUrl()), new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton("https://telegram.org?3", new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButtonTypeUrl())};
    TdApi.ReplyMarkup replyMarkup = new TdApi.ReplyMarkupInlineKeyboard(new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton[][]{row, row, row});

    TdApi.InputMessageContent content = new TdApi.InputMessageText(new TdApi.FormattedText(message, null), false, true);
    client.send(new TdApi.SendMessage(chatId, 0, false, false, replyMarkup, content), defaultHandler);
}
```

Related resources:

- [TDLib Java example](https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java)
- [`Example.java#sendMessage(long chatId, String message)`](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/java/org/drinkless/tdlib/example/Example.java#L277-L284)